# How do I read $1/3i$?

Tags: complex-numbers, notation

In a mathematical textbook I found the expression $1/3i$. Should that be read as one divided by $3i$ or as one third of $i$?

Comment: Hard to knowl. Probably $1/(3i)$. Can't you tell from the context?

Comment: This expression is unlucky. Probably $\frac{1}{3i}$ is meant, otherwise $i/3$ should have been written down.

Comment: Could be $\frac13 i$ to highlight that $\frac13$ is the imaginary part of the number.

Comment: good point @Peter  I agree with you probably $\frac 1 {3i}$

Comment: @Chris Curnow: If it was written exactly as you posted, then regardless of the intended meaning, it's very sloppy notation. Can you give a reference to the textbook?

Comment: OK. I'll come clean! It was a generic question about proof-reading maths text-books! I hope this link works, the bit that worries me is the section on fractions where it's stated that 'The denominator of a numerical fraction is assumed to end at the first non-numeric symbol. So 1/3i represents one-third of i, not 1 divided by 3i.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the rub: Matlab translates this is 1/(3i) whereas WolframAlpha says it's i/3. So pick your poison.

Answer (score 2):

That’s a bad way to write, but if I have to choose in this case my standard interpretation is $1/3i=1/(3i)$ that is $$\frac1{3i}$$

indeed to express $(1/3)i$ one could write directly $i/3$ without any ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

Well it can be both:

- $$1/\left(3i\right)=\frac{1}{3i}=\frac{i}{3ii}=-\frac{i}{3}\tag1$$
- $$\left(1/3\right)i=\frac{1}{3}\cdot i\tag2$$

Answer (score 0):

The notation $ 1/3i$ in your textbook is bad !

It can be both $\frac{1}{3}i$ and $\frac{1}{3i}$.